# Is it possible set only the storage.buckets.get permission on a account within the Google Cloud Console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How can I set this permission for a user? I only see a relevant `Storage > Storage admin` which provides `storage.buckets.*`, however I don't want this user account to have such broad permissions.

I have determined the above information from this page: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles

I would like a user to have read only permissions to a bucket.

Comment: @Digil 's answer looks correct to me. You can set the minimal rights only at the bucket level.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ACLs over objects and buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#permissions). You can give ”READER” permission for a particular user on bucket level. By giving this, the user can only read and download the object’s data.

A second approach is to give the user a Legacy Bucket IAM roles. You can give “Storage Legacy Bucket Reader ” role, which also gives the user ‘read only’ option. More details regarding  this role can be found in this [help center article](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam?hl=en_US&_ga=2.213912095.-906677091.1506349906&_gac=1.208465318.1506711504.EAIaIQobChMIgtSW1YnL1gIVj7XACh3MigukEAAYASAAEgLXi_D_BwE#acls).

Comment: Do you have knowledge what the "legacy" means for those roles? Does it mean they are going to disappear, at some relatively early stage?

Answer (score 1):

Google has [IAM Custom Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) in beta. You can use this to create a new role with the exact permission set you want.