# Google Cloud Platform IAM setting to allow project level RO access to buckets

Tags: google-cloud-storage, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam

I want to give a service account read-only access to every bucket in my project. What is the best practice for doing this?

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46524504/) suggest one of:

- creating a custom IAM policy
- assigning the Legacy Bucket Viewer role on each bucket
- using ACLs to allow `bucket.get` access

None of these seem ideal to me because:

- Giving read-only access seems too common a need to require a custom policy
- Putting "Legacy" in the name makes it seem like this permission will be retired relatively soon and any new buckets will require modification
- Google recommends [IAM over ACL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#iam-vs-acl) and any new buckets will require modification

Is there some way to avoid the `bucket.get` requirement and still access objects in the bucket? Or is there another method for providing access that I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

The closest pre-built role is Object Viewer. This allows listing and reading objects. It doesn't include storage.buckets.get permission, but this is not commonly needed - messing with bucket metadata is really an administrative function.   It also doesn't include storage.buckets.list which is a bit more commonly needed but is still not part of normal usage patterns for GCS - generally when designing an app you have a fixed number of buckets for specific purposes, so listing is not useful.

If you really do want to give a service account bucket list and get permission, you will have to create a custom role on the project. This is pretty easy, you can do it with:

```
gcloud iam roles create StorageViewerLister --project=$YOUR_POJECT --permissions=storage.objects.get,storage.objects.list,storage.buckets.get,storage.buckets.list
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $YOUR_PROJECT --member=$YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT --role=StorageViewerLister
```

Comment: I may have been too general in my question. I am using the python client library to access objects in my bucket. I create a GCS client with `client = google.cloud.storage.Client()`. From what I can tell, to get objects I must first get the bucket they're contained in via `client.get_bucket(bucket_name)`. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I thought the pattern of needing to first get the bucket was pretty universal which is why I asked the question so generally. Is that particular to python?